Accessing the RGB camera of HoloLens via Python
I'm working on a project for the calibration of the HoloLens 2. I need to access and manipulate the video feed from the RGB camera directly through a Python script. Does anyone know how I can achieve this? I came across some information online, but it was in C++, and unfortunately, I'm only familiar with Python.
Thanks in advance for any help!
